# Hide toggle button if no child divs present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to hide toggler_btn, if there are no child divs inside this certain one.
I've added data-attributes, I think something has to be done with them. Not sure though.

I've tried this:

```
$('.toggler_btn').each(function () {
            var elem_id = $(this).data('id');

            if ($('.element_wrapper[data-parent="' + elem_id + '"]').children().length === 0) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
```

And it works but maybe there's a simpler and faster way to do that?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
            <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="20" data-parent="" style="display:none">
            <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="20" data-parent="">+</button>
            Building 1
            <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
            <button class="edit_btn" type="button" data-id="20" data-parent="">Edit</button>
            <button class="delete_btn" type="button" data-id="20">Delete</button>
        <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="25" data-parent="20" style="display:none">
            <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="25" data-parent="20">+</button>
            Something Else
            <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
            <button class="edit_btn" type="button" data-id="25" data-parent="20">Edit</button>
            <button class="delete_btn" type="button" data-id="25">Delete</button>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you please include your html code?

Comment: can please add all the codes(`HTML` and `js`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this solves your problem, else let me know.

**Update:** I changed my part of it to be a bit more dynamic so it will work with multi levels

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div[data-parent=""]').show();

  $('.toggler_btn').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    if ($('.element_wrapper[data-parent="' + id + '"]').children().length > 0) {
      $('.element_wrapper[data-parent="' + id + '"]').toggle();
      if ($(this).text() === '+') {
        $(this).html('-');
      } else {
        $(this).html('+');
      }


      var t = $('.element_wrapper[data-parent="' + id + '"]').children(".toggler_btn");
      if (t.siblings(".element_wrapper").length == 0) {
        $('.element_wrapper[data-parent="' + id + '"]').children(".toggler_btn").hide();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="20" data-parent="" style="display:none">
    <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="20" data-parent="">+</button> Building 1
    <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
    <button class="edit_btn" type="button" data-id="20" data-parent="">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete_btn" type="button" data-id="20">Delete</button>
    <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="25" data-parent="20" style="display:none">
      <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="25" data-parent="20">+</button> Something Else
      <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
      <button class="edit_btn" type="button" data-id="25" data-parent="20">Edit</button>
      <button class="delete_btn" type="button" data-id="25">Delete</button>
      <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="30" data-parent="25" style="display:none">
        <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="30" data-parent="25">+</button> Something Else
        <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
        <button class="edit_btn" type="button" data-id="30" data-parent="25">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete_btn" type="button" data-id="30">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

**Update 2:** since you chanced your jquery code, I updated the second snippet to match your new code.

```js
$('.toggler_btn').each(function(i) {
  if (i == 0) {
    $(this).parent().show()
  }
  var elem_id = $(this).data('id');
  if ($('.element_wrapper[data-parent="' + elem_id + '"]').children().length === 0) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});

$('.toggler_btn').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

  if ($('.element_wrapper[data-parent="' + id + '"]').children().length > 0) {
    $('.element_wrapper[data-parent="' + id + '"]').toggle();
    if ($(this).text() === '+') {
      $(this).html('-');
    } else {
      $(this).html('+');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="20" data-parent="" style="display:none">
    <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="20" data-parent="">+</button> Building 1
    <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
    <button class="edit_btn" type="button" data-id="20" data-parent="">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete_btn" type="button" data-id="20">Delete</button>
    <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="25" data-parent="20" style="display:none">
      <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="25" data-parent="20">+</button> Something Else
      <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
      <button class="edit_btn" type="button" data-id="25" data-parent="20">Edit</button>
      <button class="delete_btn" type="button" data-id="25">Delete</button>
      <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="30" data-parent="25" style="display:none">
        <button class="toggler_btn" type="button" data-id="30" data-parent="25">+</button> Something Else
        <button class="add_btn" type="button">Add</button>
        <button class="edit_btn" type="button" data-id="30" data-parent="25">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete_btn" type="button" data-id="30">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```